# android image BG not showing all devices

Tags: android

I have an app, it was just published in the android store. I installed it on 3 different devices.

It works on the Nexus 5.

It works on the Nexus 7. (tablet)

It does not work on my LG G3 however.

In my code i have the background as a drawable, the size of which is 748 x 1067
in my content_activity.xml my root node RelativeLayout has the background set

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_secret"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.secret.secret.secret.secret"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_secret"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/thin_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/thin_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/thin_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/thin_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/old_paper_texture"
    android:backgroundTintMode="add">
```

is there any reason why this would not work on some devices? I feel it could be an image size thing... but it works on the tablet which is bigger than the phone it doesn't work on.

Comment: Did you add resource in all the densities, ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Comment: no... how does one go about doing that? i was taught to ctrl+c the image and paste it into the drawable folder. so thats all i did

Comment: go through this documentation, https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, Basically what you'll want to do is create multiple version of the background image and store them into relevant density resource directory, android will decide which resource to pick based on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxdpi, drawable-xxxhpi`